# how to delete a file, whose name consists of flags,

Tags: bash, unix

I created a file - "-i"(no quotes) and wish to remove this file via CLI.
but i am not able to do so as the file name is treated as flag. Any suggestions?

```sh
rm "-i"
rm "\-i"
rm \-i
rm ^-i$
```

All of them show that - rm: missing operand.

Comment: If you struggle with filename escapes, then another tool available on just about every linux distro is `mc` (midnight commander). You can simply use the arrow keys to highlight the file you wish to remove and press `F8`. (see `lynx like motion` in options to really make `mc` fly...) If `mc` is installed, you can simply type `mc` at the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Do this like this :

```
rm -- '-i'
```

from `man bash` :

> A  -- signals the end of options and disables further option processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as file‐names and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.

Answer (score 1):

Use a longer path: `rm ./-i` ....